# How to reduce number of "echo" in PHP?

Tags: php, html-table

I am having problem in reducing number of "echo" in following code:

Please provide a solution.

```
 echo "<br>"."<br>". "<table class='table table-striped'>";
    foreach ($result as $values) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($values as $data) {

            echo "<td>". $data. "</td>";

        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: does it really matter ??

Comment: You could concatenate the strings into a single variable and then after the foreach loop, echo the variable. This would provide you with only one echo statement.

Comment: Hi, Please have a look at my answer below. And upvote me if it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is the first step towards realising that you need a separate templating layer. There are plenty of them available (Twig, Blade, Smarty), but PHP itself can provide a good example:

```
<table class='table table-striped'>
    <?php foreach ($result as $values): ?>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach ($values as $data): ?>
                <td><?= $data; ?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

The [alternative control syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) allows you to work without littering the template with `{` and `}` everywhere, which in my opinion makes things a lot more readable. The short echo tag `<?=` is used in place of `echo`, which again removes clutter.

It's ultimately a matter of opinion, but this is a clean approach.

Answer (score 3):

It's better to keep logic and display separate, so you could make an `$output` variable and echo it once at the end!

```
<?php
    $output = "<br><br><table class='table table-striped'>";

    foreach ($result as $values) {
        $output .= "<tr>";

        foreach ($values as $data) {
            $output .="<td>". $data. "</td>";
        }
        $output .="</tr>";
    }
    $output .="</table>";

    echo $output;
```

Comment: It's better to keep **business** logic and display separate, but I don't know if that extends to making your display layer just a single `echo` statement. All templating systems still support basic control structures.

Comment: Haha, indeed! When you find yourself mixing code with a bunch of echoes however, it's definitely the way to go! Cheers Iain!

Answer (score 1):

You can take a variable instead of echoing on each stem and at last echo that variable.
For Eg. I am taking $html as variable and concatenating the table attributes in that and at last I will echo the variable and it will provide same result.

```
$html = "<br>"."<br>". "<table class='table table-striped'>";
    foreach ($result as $values) {
        $html.="<tr>";
        foreach ($values as $data) {

            $html.= "<td>". $data. "</td>";

        }
        $html.= "</tr>";
    }
    $html.= "</table>";
    // echo full table together in one variable.
    echo $html;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$string = "<br><br><table class='table table-striped'>";
foreach ($result as $values) {
    $string .= "<tr>";
    foreach ($values as $data) {

        $string .= "<td>". $data. "</td>";

    }
    $string .= "</tr>";
}
$string .= "</table>";
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this if you really want remove the `echo`'s.

```
<br><br>
 <table class='table table-striped'>
   <?php foreach ($result as $values) { ?>
      <tr>
        <?php foreach ($values as $data) { ?>

            <td><?php echo $data; ?></td>

        <?php } ?>
       </tr>
   <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

thank me later dawg

```
     echo "<br>"."<br>". "<table class='table table-striped'>";
foreach ($result as $values) { ?>
    <tr>
   <?php
    foreach ($values as $data) {
     ?>

       <td><?php echo  $data ?></td>

   <?php } ?>
    </tr
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main goal is to shorten the amount of echos right? So my code only has one :

```
<br><br><table class='table table-striped'>
<?php foreach ($result as $values) :?>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach ($values as $data) : ?>

        <td><?php echo $data ?></td>

    <?php endforeach ?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```